# Autoencoder: good loss values while fitting, but the actual performance is bad

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, autoencoder

I'm implementing a 1D convolutional autoencoder to reduce the dimensionality of an array. Here is my architecture:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(25088,1))
enc = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(input_layer)
enc = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(enc)
enc = BatchNormalization()(enc) 
enc = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(enc)
enc = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(enc)
enc = BatchNormalization()(enc)
enc = Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(enc)
enc = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, padding='same')(enc)
enc = BatchNormalization()(enc)

dec = Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(enc)
dec = UpSampling1D(2)(dec)
enc = BatchNormalization()(dec)
dec = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(dec)
dec = UpSampling1D(2)(dec)
enc = BatchNormalization()(dec) 
dec = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(dec)
dec = UpSampling1D(2)(dec)
dec = BatchNormalization()(dec)
dec = Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='sigmoid')(dec)

mod = Model(input_layer, dec)
mod.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
mod.summary()
```

And this is the summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, 25088, 1)]        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_22 (Conv1D)           (None, 25088, 32)         96        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_9 (MaxPooling1 (None, 12544, 32)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_18 (Batc (None, 12544, 32)         128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_23 (Conv1D)           (None, 12544, 16)         1040      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_10 (MaxPooling (None, 6272, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_19 (Batc (None, 6272, 16)          64        
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_24 (Conv1D)           (None, 6272, 8)           264       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_11 (MaxPooling (None, 3136, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_20 (Batc (None, 3136, 8)           32        
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_25 (Conv1D)           (None, 3136, 8)           136       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling1d_9 (UpSampling1 (None, 6272, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_26 (Conv1D)           (None, 6272, 16)          272       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling1d_10 (UpSampling (None, 12544, 16)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_27 (Conv1D)           (None, 12544, 32)         1056      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling1d_11 (UpSampling (None, 25088, 32)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_23 (Batc (None, 25088, 32)         128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_28 (Conv1D)           (None, 25088, 1)          65        
=================================================================
Total params: 3,281
Trainable params: 3,105
Non-trainable params: 176
```

My 'data' matrix is a matrix 24 x 25088. I first normalize the values, dividing each row array (so each sample) by the maximum value of that sample's features, in order to have numbers in the [0, 1] range. Then I launch the fitting of the model:

```
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
  data[i] = (data[i] / np.max(data[i]))

mod.fit(data, data, epochs=200, batch_size=12, verbose=1, callbacks=[callback])
```

And at the final epoch the computed loss is equal to 0.0043, which seems to be a good value.
I tried to compute the model's prediction for one of the arrays on which it was trained. More specifically, the array in the first row of the `data` matric. Let's call this array `d`. These are the values for the first 20 columns:

```
d = data[:1]
print(d[0, :20])
```

```
[[0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]
 [0.01939528]
 [0.        ]
 [0.        ]]
```

We now compute the model prediction for the `d` input and print the first 20 values:

```
pred = mod.predict(d)
print(pred[0, :20])
```

And this is the output, which should be similar to the input but this is not the case:

```
[[0.04406765]
 [0.04403916]
 [0.04400587]
 [0.04404509]
 [0.04407492]
 [0.04407457]
 [0.04407048]
 [0.04407695]
 [0.04408097]
 [0.04407555]
 [0.04405355]
 [0.0440937 ]
 [0.04411143]
 [0.0441142 ]
 [0.04412091]
 [0.044112  ]
 [0.04410812]
 [0.0446077 ]
 [0.04569775]
 [0.04390234]]
```

I've never used autoencoders before. Why do I obtain an acceptable loss value, but then the actual model performance is not good? What can I do to improve the performance?

Comment: You should evaluate if your model is overfitting, e.g. by measuring the performance on a validation set after each epoch and then checking the loss curves.

Comment: If it's overfitting it should give good results on the training data, but this is not the case. The array on which I tested the model was also used for the training

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I had not realized that.

Comment: How many data points do you have? From your text "My 'data' matrix is a matrix 24 x 25088" I understand, that you have 24 data points. Is this so?

Comment: Yes, that's correct